# Pass a string with XML content as a parameter to WCF

Tags: wcf

I'm having a problem when passing a parameter to the WCF service. The parameter is a string consisting of XML text. When I try to send to WCF, I get the error "Server not found", however, if I do any other operation using the service, I have no error.

I took a look on google, I even saw a few tips and tested with changing the size of the messages in the web.config and servicereference.clientconfig, but so far nothing.

Has anyone had this problem there that can help?

Regards.

Comment: I don't think the fact that you're passing an xml string has anything to do with the error you're getting. That said: Please post some code along with the stack trace of the error you're getting.

Comment: Enable tracing for the WCF service and client (start with server) and check your logs. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx for enabling tracing in WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there aren't any issues passing XML in your string parameter. You need to [turn WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on within your service to see what's really going on. I suspect you're exceeding the MaxReceivedMessageSize.

Also make sure binding textEncoding is correct.

Comment: I have tryed to Trace but with no success.
My web.config file have this code:


    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GEDService.basicHttpBinding0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  

Anything is wrong?

Comment: When you say you tried Trace with no success, what do you mean? Did you get an exception in the Trace output file?

Comment: On the config, looks ok, does your client match?

Comment: I run the app but the trace output file is not created. What means "Client match"?

Comment: The trace config isn't setup properly then. It needs to be in the config file on the server side, not the client side. "Client match" means that the config settings for your WCF client need to match the config of your WCF service.

Comment: I'm developing in VS2010, is not in production. Where can I change the config in the "server"? My ServiceReferences.ClientConfig snippet code: <basicHttpBinding>
                
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_GEDService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>

Comment: In the web.config or app.config of the project that has your service. If you're doing standard WCF out of the box, find the project with your SVC file, find the web.config, and add the system.diagnostics tracing config section from the link in my answer.

Comment: Here is an image of my Web.Config: http://img828.imageshack.us/i/webconfig.jpg/ , something is wrong to do the trace?

Comment: Yep - move the system.diagnostics section up a level, it needs to be directly under the <configuration> section.

Comment: Hey... I don't know what's wrong, I do what you say, but the AppLog.svclog was not generated, however, I got a different error before the error of "server not found", the error is: "XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding"

Comment: Are you using IIS? Does IIS have permission to write to the root of the C drive? A couple things...one, let me see your service contract, and two, try passing your xml string surrounded with a single quote like this string valueToPass = "'<xml>blah</xml>'"; service.SomeMethod(valueToPass);

Comment: I'm not using IIS, I'm using VS2010 directly. I tested writing a short xml code, and yes, it WORKS. What I saw is: I need to pass a xml with UTF-16 encoding. I was passing a UTF-8. This fix the problem. Brandon, so thanks man, you help a LOOOT! But, and about the WCF trace, what you think is going on?

Comment: Good job! My guess is that VS 2010 doesn't have permission to write to the root of the C: drive. You could create a folder C:\temp and try to write there. If you're on Windows 7, make sure you run Visual Studio as Admin. I will update my answer so that if someone finds this in the future they know what to do.